# Doctrine Migrations: Multiple Schemas With Same Table Name

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I am working on integrating Doctrine Migrations into an existing project and in migration files, whenever I call methods on `Schema`(ex. `$schema->getTables()`), I get this error:

```
Executing dry run of migration up to 20180726185129 from 0

  ++ migrating 20180726185129

IN UP
Migration 20180726185129 failed during Execution. Error An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT quote_ident(r.conname) as conname, pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true) as condef
                  FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint r
                  WHERE r.conrelid =
                  (
                      SELECT c.oid
                      FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
                      WHERE n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema', 'pg_toast') AND c.relname = 'config' AND n.nspname = ANY(string_to_array((select replace(replace(setting,'"$user"',user),' ','') from pg_catalog.pg_settings where name = 'search_path'),',')) AND n.oid = c.relnamespace
                  )
                  AND r.contype = 'f'':

SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 7 ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 91:

  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT quote_ident(r.conname) as con  
  name, pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true) as condef                 
                    FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint r                            
                    WHERE r.conrelid =                                         
                    (                                                          
                        SELECT c.oid                                           
                        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n  
                        WHERE n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_sc  
  hema', 'pg_toast') AND c.relname = 'config' AND n.nspname = ANY(string_to_a  
  rray((select replace(replace(setting,'"$user"',user),' ','') from pg_catalo  
  g.pg_settings where name = 'search_path'),',')) AND n.oid = c.relnamespace   
                    )                                                          
                    AND r.contype = 'f'':                                      

  SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 7 ERROR:  more than one row returne  
  d by a subquery used as an expression                                        


In PDOConnection.php line 106:

  SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 7 ERROR:  more than one row returne  
  d by a subquery used as an expression                                        


In PDOConnection.php line 104:

  SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 7 ERROR:  more than one row returne  
  d by a subquery used as an expression
```

I think this is because I have tables named `config` in two schemas which is why it's getting two rows. I'm not sure how to avoid this issue and there's no option to declare default Schema in `migrations.xml` or `migrations-db.php` either.

I would really like to use DBAL in migrations but unfortunately, this leaves me with no option but to use `this->addSql()`.

Comment: did you ever figure out what the issue was/is? having exactly the same issue